# GradCAM for MoViNet

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden, tensorflow-gradient

I am trying to implement GradCAM using the MoViNet a2-stream backbone with a finetuned classifier on my custom dataset, but I am struggling to build the gradient model.

When building a MoViNet model, according to the *summary()* method, we get three layers: Images (input), Movinet (backbone), and the custom classifier. My questions are:

- First, I am not sure where to find the last convolutional layer for computing gradients. Looking at the [A2-architecture graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhynf.png) in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.11511v2), I guess I need to access the *conv_7* layer, but not sure if it is included in the Movinet backbone or the Classifier.
- If I assume this last convolutional layer is the *head* sublayer in the backbone (found with *summary()* method), I get the following error when running this chunk of code for building the gradient model:

  ```py
  movinet_backbone = finetuned_model.get_layer('movinet')
  gradModel = Model(inputs=movinet_backbone.inputs,
                    outputs=[movinet_model.get_layer('head').output, finetuned_model.output])
  ```

  ```py
  ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs'), name='inputs', description="created by layer 'inputs'") at layer "stem". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
  ```

  I am not sure that I am selecting the correct layer with this approach, as this *head* layer is part of the frozen backbone and, therefore, not trained. However, I am getting this error with any other layer in the backbone. At the same time, the classifier layer does not contain nested layers to access. I also do not know how to deal with all the state blocks provided when running `movinet_model.get_layer('head').output`.
- Do you think GradCAM is actually feasible with this type of architecture?

I would appreciate any feedback provided. Thanks.

**Notes**: I have followed the training procedure explained in [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/projects/movinet/movinet_streaming_model_training_and_inference.ipynb) without any issues. I can also load and evaluate the finetuned model.